# R: Replacing NAs in not-entirely-NA rows with 0, leaving entirely-NA rows empty

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a very large data frame (47000x45). In this, 43 of the columns are frequencies of some objects (say, different cat breeds) in a particular location for a particular year- that is, for each (cat breed, location) pair, I have 43 frequencies, one for each year.

These frequencies were found by merging a data frame of total number of observations of all cats from that location in a particular year (table1), and a data frame of observations of how many observations of a particular breed of cat from that location in a particular year (table2), then dividing to find frequency. The table was then reformatted to express frequency as a "time-series" of sorts, with years as columns to describe the time-evolution of each (breed, location) pair. All missing values in this time series are replaced with NAs. Herein lies my issue.

I have realised that there are in fact "2 kinds of NAs" in my table- one stemming from the fact that no cats were seen at all in that location in that year (and hence missing from table 1), and the other as a result of no cats of that particular breed seen despite other cats being seen in that location in that year (and hence entry missing from table 2).

Naturally, the second kind of NA is not really an NA- it is rather a zero, as no cats of that frequency were reported. Hence, I would like to replace such NAs with 0.

One approach might be to add the missing info into table 2, associated with value 0. By finding the pairs of (location, year) that are non-zero (where cats were seen), I can try proceeding by filling in all the cases in Table 2 where there is a non-zero (location, year) pair but not a single cat of a particular breed seen. Unfortunately, there are too many cat breeds for me to just set the complement of all of them to 0 and add all of them to the data. I have been trying to achieve this using anti-join and merge functions, but without success.

Another approach would be that in the reorganised "time series" table, since any column having a non-zero value means that some cats must have been observed at that location that year, all other NAs in that column must be replaced with zeroes, while columns that contain exclusively NAs must be left as such.

However, I do not know how to proceed with either of these- any tips would be appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

I have tried using anti-join and merge on subsets of the data, but have not been able to introduce this "new" data of 0, only subset and complement the existing information.

Using group_by(location) and mutate(across(years), ~ifelse(all(is.na(.)), ., is.na(.)<-0)) for the second approach. Gives error that `..2` must be a vector, not a formula object.

SAMPLE CODE

```
loc <- c("L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3")
brd <- c("Persian", "Shorthair", "Sphinx", "Persian", "Shorthair", "Sphinx", "Siamese")
yr2021 <- c("0.5", NA, "0.3", "0.3", NA, "0.2", "0.5")
yr2022 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "0.3", "0.7", "0.4", "0.6")
tab <- as.data.frame(cbind(loc, brd, yr2021, yr2022))
```

This is the format of data I currently have. Note that in L1, in 2021, cats were seen, but Shorthair says NA. Hence, this should be a 0. However, in L1, in 2022, it appears that no cat has a non-zero frequency, and thus, no cats were seen, and hence this column remains NA.

Comment: I think this will be much clearer (and give us something to help with) if you could share a small reproducible example of input and (preferably) the corresponding desired output--though I understand you have a couple possibilities there. 5-10 rows of sample data in valid copy/pasteable syntax is nicest. You can use `dput()` to create syntax to create an R object, perhaps `dput(your_data[1:10, 1:3])` for the first 10 rows and 3 columns would work - choose appropriate rows and columns to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Also, seeing the actual code you tried, rather than just descriptions of it, will be much more useful for us to help debug it.

Comment: You may want to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following achieves what you need:

```
library(dplyr)

tab %>%
        group_by(loc) %>%
        mutate(across(starts_with('yr'),~ifelse(!all(is.na(.x)) & is.na(.x),"0",.x )))



# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   loc [3]
  loc   brd       yr2021 yr2022
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>
1 L1    Persian   0.5    NA
2 L1    Shorthair 0      NA
3 L1    Sphinx    0.3    NA
4 L2    Persian   0.3    0.3
5 L2    Shorthair 0      0.7
6 L3    Sphinx    0.2    0.4
7 L3    Siamese   0.5    0.6
```